# Paypal going live payment not showing in my account

Tags: e-commerce, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, paypal

OK so I have a verified business account setup. Im using the express checkout API and tested it in Sandbox, all was working fine, so I changed the `API_Uname, pword, signature` to correspond with the details for the live environment.

I made a small purchase with my boyfriends credit card just to check that everything is working...(Im selling digital goods), The card was charged and I assumed all is in order

**My Problem**

Eventhough the credit card was charged, there are no payments / orders / customers etc showing in my account. Surely because my boyfriends card was charged the payment should reflect in my account but nothing is showing...?!

I have read extensively through the developers documentation and came up with the following 2 conclusions:

1. Developers dashboard says I have no registered apps, yet I have live login credentials (uname,pword,signature) on my account...and my account is verified, could this be the reason?
2. Setting up the API I did something wrong which results in the card being charged, client getting content but me not getting paid...Could this be possible?

Assuming either one of above mentioned is correct surely paypal should have thrown an error or blocked the transaction..?

Has anyone else experienced this problem before? Any pointers or tips will be greatly appreciated

Comment: If the card was actually charged then the money went into a PayPal account somewhere.  Are you sure it was actually charged, or are you just saying that because the checkout completed successfully?  It's possible you're still hitting the sandbox when you think you're hitting the live server, for example.  Which API specifically are you using?  DoDirectPayment?  PayFlow?

Comment: @AndrewAngell thanks for contributing...Im saying the card was charged because the checkout completed successfully...and user could access content(Have yet to check bank statement to confirm if money was deducted) "It's possible you're still hitting the sandbox when you think you're hitting the live server" I get what you are saying but I changed the Sandbox credentials....so how is that possible? Im using express checkout for digital goods! p.s Must you first submit your website to paypal for review before you can accept live payments?

Comment: Express Checkout does not require an app approval if you're using the Classic API.  Are you using SetExpressCheckout, GetExpressCheckoutDetails, and DoExpressCheckoutPayment?  Do you have logs of the requests and responses?

Comment: When using Express Checkout for digital goods, you do have to have digital goods enabled in the live account.